# How to formulate equation for ARIMA models?

Tags: forecasting, arima, autoregressive, moving-average

I have tried to generate/write equation for forecasting using ARIMA models. But I think my equations were wrong and I am stuck with it. Kindly please help me to obtain equations for

1.(ARIMA (0,1,2)
ma1 ma2= -0.1704, 0.4193
s.e s.e= 0.1259, 0.1646
σ^2,    log likelihood= 127.7, -179.84

2. SARIMA (1,0,0)(0,1,0)12
   ar1 = 0.7076
   s.e = 0.1304
   σ^2,    log likelihood= 450.1, -160.89
3. ARIMA (0,1,3)

ma1,    ma2,    ma3= -0.4932,   0.1227, -0.3997
s.e s.e s.e= 0.1326, 0.179, 0.1384
σ^2 log likelihood= 333.2,  -202.12

4. SARIMA (1,0,0)(1,1,0)12

ar1,    sar1= 0.4605,   -0.722
s.e s.e= 0.1463,    0.1061
σ^2 log likelihood= 423.4,  -163.46

5. ARIMA (0,1,1)
   ma1= -0.464
   s.e= 0.167
   σ^2 log likelihood= 2384,   -249.05
6. ARIMA (1,1,1)
   ar1,        ma1= 0.394, -0.9023
   s.e     s.e= 0.1804, 0.0898
   σ^2 log likelihood= 393.5,  -206.57
7. ARIMA (0,1,1)
   ma1= -0.7823
   s.e = 0.0987
   σ^2 log likelihood= 499.4,  -212.67

Is there anything I am missing for formulating the equation?

Comment: This question cannot be answered without the time series data.  You may not need to look at so many models when you look at partial autocorrelation and autocorrelation functions.

Comment: Please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=arima+equation for many similar questions.